# Codificar el pseudocódigo para intercalar los datos de un archivo

Tags: c++, ordenamiento

Necesito llenar el archivo *numeros.txt* con el contenido de los archivos *impar.txt* y *par.txt* (números enteros) de manera que quede ordenado. El contenido de los archivos es el siguiente:

```
impar.txt = 1 5 15 25 33
par.txt = 6 8 10 12 50 60 70
```

Generando el archivo numeros.txt

```
numeros.txt = 1 5 6 8 10 12 15 25 33 50 60 70
```

Los archivos .txt **sólo contienen dígitos** y cada dígito está en una línea, es decir, que están escritos de manera vertical.

Para este problema **no puedo utilizar un método de ordenamiento** como burbuja, selección o shell; sino que tengo que intercalar los archivos. **Tampoco puedo utilizar arreglos o vectores para almacenar el contenido de impar.txt y par.txt**

Tengo el siguiente pseudocódigo:

```
Leer par.txt
Leer impar.txt
Mientras existan registros en los 2 archivos
    Comparar
    Si llave par.txt < llave de impar.txt
        Guardar datos de llave de par.txt en numeros.txt
        Leer par.txt
    Si no
        Guardar datos de llave de impar.txt en numeros.txt
        Leer impar.txt
    Fin
Como ya se acabo uno de los 2 archivos
    Guardar los registros restantes en numeros.txt
```

Y tengo el siguiente código:

```
/* Abrir los archivos impar.txt y par.txt */
Impar.open("impar.txt");
Par.open("par.txt");    
/* Crear numeros.txt*/
/* Intercalar */
        Numeros.open("numeros.txt");

        // Variables para almacenar los números
        // y así poder compararlos.
        int a, b;
        a = b = 0;
        // Contadores para los dos archivos
        int contador;
        // Para determinar cual archivo fue el primero en leerse
        char letra;

        while(!Impar.eof() && !Par.eof()){
            // a -> Impar
            // b -> Par

            // Cuando a = b = 0
            if(a == b){
                Impar >> a;
                Par >> b;
            }
            else if(a < b){
                Numeros << a << endl;
                Impar >> a;
            }
            else if(a > b){
                Numeros << b << endl;
                Par >> b;
            }
            contador++;
            if(Impar.eof() == true){
                letra = 'I';
                break;
            }
            else if(Par.eof() == true){
                letra = 'P';
                break;
            }
        }
        // Si Impar fue el primero en acabar <-- Aquí hay un error.
        int i = 0;
        int c = 0;
        if(letra == 'I'){
            while(!Par.eof()){
                if(i == contador){
                    Par >> c; // <---- No parece funcionar con ningún valor.
                              // E.g. contador = contador -1, contador = 4
                }
                if(i >= contador){
                    Numeros << c << endl;
                    Par >> c;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        // Si Par fue el primero en acabar
        else if(letra == 'P'){
            while(!Impar.eof()){
                if(i >= contador){
                    Numeros << c << endl;
                    Impar >> c;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        Numeros.close();
```

Lo que genera lo siguiente en mi archivo *numeros.txt*

```
1
5
6
8
10
12
15
25
33
60
70
```

Lo cual es un error, ya que debería quedar:

```
1
5
6
8
10
12
15
25
33
50
60
70
```

Si al declarar **c** le doy un valor de 50 el programa funciona, pero sólo en este caso específico donde tengo ciertos números en los archivos *par.txt* e *impar.txt* ¿Alguna idea sobre como corregirlo?

Comment: ¿Se garantiza que los números en los archivos impar.txt y par.txt estén ordenados?

Comment: Sí, esos archivos contienen los datos que se indican al principio del post.

Comment: Cual es el contenido exacto del archivo par.txt e impar.txt? es ambiguo lo que escribes: podria ser "impar.txt = [1, 5, 15, 25, 33]" o "[1, 5, 15, 25, 33]" o "1, 5, 15, 25, 33" o cada número en una linea.

Comment: Me parece que con las correcciones que hice el problema ha quedado más claro.

Comment: Tal y como has puesto la pregunta, ¿se puede asumir que los números de _impar.txt_ y _par.txt_ están ordenados?

Comment: Hola @akko. Gracias por contribuir la solución final. Siguiendo el formato de preguntas y respuestas que utilizamos y al que estamos acostumbrados, en vez de editar la pregunta, podrías publicar el código final como una **respuesta**. Esto garantiza que futuros lectores que están acostumbrados al sitio puedan leer tu solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Este es un ejercicio de programación clásico**, además que ejemplifica un caso que nos podemos llegar a encontrar... unir dos series de datos que ya están ordenados y que son más grandes que la memoria que tenemos disponibles... o que no sabemos en realidad cuanto ocupan (pueden ser dos streams de datos que no sabemos que longitud tienen). Cómo te dicen en otra respuesta, sin poder copiarlos a memoria es más difícil de hacer, pero solo un poco más.

Tu código es casi correcto, solo estás cometiendo el error de leer siempre de los dos ficheros y guardas el menor... primero lees el 1 y el 6, y guardas el 1, a continuación lees de los dos ficheros, lo que te devuelve el 5 y el 8; se guarda el 5. Vuelves a leer de los dos, te traes el 15 y el 10, y guardas el 10... y así hasta que se te acaba uno de los dos ficheros. Lo que deberías hacer es reemplazar el dato que acabas de guardar... por ejemplo, si guardas un número par (porque es el menor) solo debes leer del fichero de pares. Lees de los dos ficheros el 1 y el 6, guardas el 1 y lees el 5 del fichero impar. Ahora guardas el 5 y lees el siguiente valor del fichero impar, en este caso el 15, y como el menor ahora es el valor par (6) ahora guardas este y lees del fichero par, que te da el 8. Sigues así hasta leer todos los números de los dos ficheros.

En tu código deberías reemplazar:

```
while(!Impar.eof() && !Par.eof()){
    // a -> Impar
    // b -> Par
    if(a < b){
        Numeros << a << endl;
    }
    else if(a > b){
        Numeros << b << endl;
    }
    Impar >> a;
    Par >> b;
    contador++;
    if(Impar.eof() == true){
        letra = 'I';
        break;
    }
    else if(Par.eof() == true){
        letra = 'P';
        break;
    }
}
```

por (lo he hecho de cabeza, sin compilador, por lo que no he verificado que no tenga errores sintácticos)

```
// Lectura inicial de valores
Impar >> a;
Par >> b;
while(!Impar.eof() && !Par.eof()){
    if(Impar.eof() == false && a < b){
        Numeros << a << endl;
        Impar >> a;
    }
    else if(Par.eof() == false && a > b){
        Numeros << b << endl;
        Par >> b;
    }
    contador++;
}
```

Tal como he puesto antes, el programa leerá un nuevo valor par o impar únicamente en el caso de que haya guardado un valor par o impar. En el caso de que se terminen los números en uno de los dos ficheros, solo se seguirá leyendo del otro fichero.

Por cierto, los breaks que has puesto dentro de los if harán que se salga del while en cuanto se terminen los datos de uno de los dos ficheros, cuando por la descripción que haces, se deberían de copiar todos los números de los dos ficheros.

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Con esto pude codificar la parte donde ambos archivos están abiertos, sólo me falta corregir un problema en la parte donde tengo que escribir el resto del archivo que aún tiene números por leer.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Con tu observación de la instrucción break di con la correcta solución de mi problema.

Comment: De nada, me alegro que haya sido de utilidad.

Answer (score 1):

Sin poder leer los archivos en memória, es mas lioso. Asumo que los datos son **enteros mayores o iguales que 0**, para poder usar -1 para los errores.

No tengo un compilador a mano, pero más o menos sería así. Creo que se entiende.

```
// Devuelve el número MENOR en un archivo.
FUNCION BuscaMenor( archivo )
  VAR ret = INT_MAX; //std::limits<>, creo.
  VAR valor;

  REBOBINA( archivo )

  MIENTRAS( valor = LEER( archivo ) )
    SI valor < ret ENTONCES
      ret = valor;
  FIN MIENTRAS

  RETORNA ret;
FIN FUNCION

// Devuelve el valor MAYOR que el indicado.
// -1 si hay errores o no se encuentra el valor.
FUNCION BuscaMayor( archivo, valor )
  VAR ret = valor;
  VAR dato;

  REBOBINA( archivo );

  MIENTRAS( dato = LEER( archivo ) )
    SI dato > ret ENTONCES
      ret = dato;
  FIN MIENTRAS

  SI ERROR( archivo ) ENTONCES
    RETORNA -1;

  RETORNA ret;
FIN FUNCION

FUNCION PRINCIPAL( ) 
  VAR actual = BuscaMenor( archivo1 );
  VAR temp = BuscaMenor( archivo2 );
  VAR dato1;
  VAR dato2;

  SI actual > temp ENTONCES
    actual = temp;

 REPETIR SIEMPRE
  dato1 = BuscaMayor( archivo1, actual );

  // Optimización.
  SI dato1 == ( actual + 1 ) ENTONCES
    actual = dato1;
    IMPRIMIR dato1;
    REPETIR
  FIN SI

  dato2 = BuscaMayor( archivo2, actual );

  // Optimización.
  SI dato2 == ( actual + 1 ) ENTONCES
    actual = dato2;
    IMPRIMIR dato2;
    REPETIR
  FIN SI

  // Comprobamos si llegamos al final de los archivos.
  SI ( dato1 == -1 ) Y ( dato2 == -1 ) ENTONCES
    FIN

  temp = dato1;
  SI dato2 < dato1 ENTONCES
    temp = dato2;
  FIN SI

  IMPRIMIR temp;
  actual = temp;
FIN REPETIR
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta fue la solución final.

```
/* Abrir los archivos impar.txt y par.txt */
Impar.open("impar.txt");
Par.open("par.txt");
if(Impar.fail() || Par.fail()){
    cout << "Error al abrir los archivos." << endl;
    cin.ignore().get();
    exit(1);
}           
/* Intercalar */
Numeros.open("numeros.txt");            
// Variables para almacenar los números
// y así poder compararlos.
int a, b;
Impar >> a;
Par >> b;                       
// Mientras los archivos llegan al final
while(!Impar.eof() || !Par.eof()){
    // a -> Impar
    // b -> Par     
    // Uno de los archivos aún no llegan al final
    if(!Impar.eof() && !Par.eof()){
        if(a < b){
            Numeros << a << endl;
            Impar >> a;
        }
        else if(a > b){
            Numeros << b << endl;
            Par >> b;
        }
    }               
    // Impar aún no llega al final
    else if(!Impar.eof() && Par.eof()){
        Numeros << a << endl;
        Impar >> a;
    }
    // Par aún no llega al final
    else if(!Par.eof() && Impar.eof()){
        Numeros << b << endl;
        Par >> b;
    }
}           
Numeros.close();
```